# Google Closure Conditional Rendering

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I have an issue whereby I have a snippet of code to be rendered in a template only once. The template in question is actually loaded multiple times when the user scrolls down a certain amount (infinite scrolling), so currently the below code is rendered multiple times...

```
    <div id="tabAd" name="ad"></div>
    <div id="mobAd" name="ad"></div>
{/template}
```

Is there an inbuilt function where google closure can detect a template has already been loaded (even with ajax requests)? or what is the best solution to make these divs load just the once?

Hopefully I explained that well enough!

Comment: You are using Closure Templates?  So your template should start with `{template .myname}` right? What is the code snippet? Is it the template or something else?

Comment: Don't worry @owler I ended up just passing a boolean flag from the back end and using that as a check in a google closure conditional :) seems to work. Thanks though

Comment: @Gordo consider to answer your own question.